# Multivariate asymmetric generalized gaussian distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, skewness, bivariate, skew-normal-distribution

I would like to write the distribution of a multivariate asymmetric generalized gaussian distribution and plot the result with Matlab.
So far I was able to write the code to create a bivariate symmetric generalized gaussian distribution given a covariance matrix $\Sigma$, the mean $\mu$ and a shape parameter $\beta$, like I found on this paper: [Verdoolaege et al. 2011](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225264984_On_the_Geometry_of_Multivariate_Generalized_Gaussian_Models?enrichId=rgreq-afe8e3f1-8b6a-4ad3-bf6f-c3f8b428115e&enrichSource=Y292ZXJQYWdlOzIyNTI2NDk4NDtBUzoxMDI0OTUyMjUzODQ5NjJAMTQwMTQ0ODE3NDE0Mw%3D%3D&el=1_x_2).
The result is this:[image: Generalized gaussian with $\mu = 0$ and $\beta = 6$]

Now I would like to create an asymmetric distribution function (basically, change the shape of the ellipse so that it is "elongated" on one side of the x or y axis: i.e. , it has a $\Sigma_l$ and a $\Sigma_r$ that are different on the left and right side of the mean point (along one dimension is also fine to start with). Similar to what they do here: [Elguebaly 2013](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225264984_On_the_Geometry_of_Multivariate_Generalized_Gaussian_Models?enrichId=rgreq-afe8e3f1-8b6a-4ad3-bf6f-c3f8b428115e&enrichSource=Y292ZXJQYWdlOzIyNTI2NDk4NDtBUzoxMDI0OTUyMjUzODQ5NjJAMTQwMTQ0ODE3NDE0Mw%3D%3D&el=1_x_2) and [Nandi and Mämpel](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/001600329500029W) (Eq. 3) but I don't know how to apply this to my bivariate case. Do you know how can I do this or do you have better suggestions for another distribution that I can use in this case? I am actually trying to implement exactly the code from Elguebaly in Matlab but didn't manage yet. 
[image]

I think the result should be something similar, but more flat on the top (with another $\beta$):
[image]

Taken from: [Multivariate skew densities](http://www.timberlake-consultancy.com/slaurent/pdf/Mult_SKST7.pdf).

The Matlab code that I used so far for the bivariate symmetric case is this one:

```
sx = 0.003; sy = 0.001; 
sigma = [sx 0;0 sy];
mu = [0 0];
beta = 6; % Shape parameter
% Define the grid for visualisation
[X,Y] = meshgrid(linspace(-2*sqrt(sx),2*sqrt(sx),50),linspace(-2*sqrt(sy),2*sqrt(sy),50));
% Define the constant
const = (gamma(1)/(pi*gamma(1/beta)*2^(1/beta)))*beta/sqrt(det(sigma));
% Compute Density at every point on the grid
temp = [X(:)-mu(1) Y(:)-mu(2)];
pdf = const*exp(-0.5*diag(temp*inv(sigma)*temp').^beta);
pdf = reshape(pdf,size(X));
figure, 
surfc(X, Y, pdf, 'LineStyle', 'none');
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Btw, only your first link is free, you other two links are not accessible to everyone. Oh, an you have to edit the original question and not to add a comment/edit as an answer.

Comment: Thank you, I modified according to what you said. But I don't know how to attach the papers that are not free. I just copied the most relevant equation.